# Change parent state from child using React hook

Tags: javascript, react-native

Newbie here, I have a page where a user adds and removes input forms by pressing an add/remove button. Each `<InputCard/>` item has a few `<TextInput/>` fields. I need changes to these `<InputCard/>` items to change the state in the parent component. When the `<TextInput/>` values change in each/any of the `<InputCard/>` items, I need this change reflected in the parent `formState`. Code is below:

****InputScreen.js****

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, ScrollView, FlatList } from 'react-native';
import { Button, Caption } from 'react-native-paper';
import InputCard from '../components/InputCard';

const InputScreen = props => {
    const [inputList, setInputList] = useState([]);
    const [formState, setFormState] = useState([]);
    const addInput = () => {
        setInputList(inputList.concat(<InputCard key={inputList.length} />));
        setFormState([
            ...formState,
            {
                id: inputList.length,
                substance: "",
                amount: "",
                measure: ""
            },
        ]);
    };

    const handleInputChange = () => {
        // each card has 3 input fields and needs to update the corresponding values in formState
        // where the InputCard key and formState id are corresponding
    };
    
    const removeLastInput = () => {
        if (inputList.length > 0) {
            const lastindex = inputList.length - 1;
            setFormState(formState.filter((item, index) => index !== lastindex));
            setInputList(inputList.filter((item, index) => index !== lastindex));       
        }
    };

    return (
        <ScrollView>
            <View style={styles.col}>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <Caption>What substances are you using?</Caption>
                </View>
                <View style={styles.row}>
                    <View>
                        {inputList}
                    </View>
                </View>
                <View>
                    <View style={styles.col}>
                        <Button title='Add' onPress={addInput}>Add</Button>
                    </View>
                    <View style={styles.col}>
                        <Button title='Remove' onPress={removeLastInput}>Remove</Button>
                    </View>
                </View>
            </View>
        </ScrollView>
    )
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#c1f5f5',
      paddingVertical: 20,
      paddingHorizontal: 20
    },
    col: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        paddingVertical: 10,
      },
    row: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    rowright: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    half : {
        width: '50%',
        paddingRight: 5,
    },
    quarter : {
        width: '25%',
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
    },
    quarterlast : {
        width: '25%',
        paddingLeft: 5,
    },
    third : {
        width: '33%',
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
    },
    thirdlast : {
        width: '33%',
        paddingLeft: 5,
    },
    substanceconfig : {
        backgroundColor: '#E1F7F7',
        fontSize: 12,
    },
    textfield : {
        borderColor: '#1e5c64',
        borderWidth: 2,
    },
    dropdown: {
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        borderColor: '#1e5c64',
        borderRadius: 7,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 14
    },
    iconbutton: {
        backgroundColor: '#1e5c64',
        color: '#ffffff',
    },
    slider: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 60
    },
    flex1: {
        flex: 1
    }
});

export default InputScreen;
```

****InputCard.js****

```
import React from "react";
import { View, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { Caption, Card, TextInput } from "react-native-paper";

const InputCard = (props, { formState, handleChange }) => {

    const key = props.key;    

    return (
        <View>
            <Card>
                <Card.Content>
                    <Caption>Item {key}</Caption>
                    <View style={styles.row}>
                        <View style={styles.half}>
                            <TextInput
                                label="substance"
                                value={formState[key].substance}
                                onChangeText={handleChange} // change needs to be made from here to parent
                                mode="outlined"
                                right={<TextInput.Icon name="pill" />}
                                style={styles.textfield}
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.quarter}>
                            <TextInput
                                label="amount"
                                value={formState[key].amount}
                                onChangeText={handleChange}
                                mode="outlined"
                                keyboardType="number-pad"
                            />
                        </View>
                        <View style={styles.quarterlast}>
                            <TextInput
                                label="measure"
                                value={formState[key].measure}
                                onChangeText={handleChange}
                                mode="outlined"
                            />
                        </View>
                    </View>
                </Card.Content>
            </Card>
        </View>
    );
}

export default InputCard;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
      backgroundColor: '#c1f5f5',
      paddingVertical: 20,
      paddingHorizontal: 20
    },
    col: {
        flexDirection: 'column',
        paddingVertical: 10,
      },
    row: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
    },
    rowright: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    },
    half : {
        width: '50%',
        paddingRight: 5,
    },
    quarter : {
        width: '25%',
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
    },
    quarterlast : {
        width: '25%',
        paddingLeft: 5,
    },
    third : {
        width: '33%',
        paddingHorizontal: 5,
    },
    thirdlast : {
        width: '33%',
        paddingLeft: 5,
    },
    substanceconfig : {
        backgroundColor: '#E1F7F7',
        fontSize: 12,
    },
    textfield : {
        borderColor: '#1e5c64',
        borderWidth: 2,
    },
    dropdown: {
        height: 60,
        backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
        borderColor: '#1e5c64',
        borderRadius: 7,
        borderWidth: 1,
        padding: 14
    },
    iconbutton: {
        backgroundColor: '#1e5c64',
        color: '#ffffff',
    },
    slider: {
        flex: 1,
        height: 60
    },
    flex1: {
        flex: 1
    }
});
```

Comment: What's the problem/question you have about the current code? How is it not working, specifically?

Comment: I just don't know how I should implement `handleInputChange` in the child component, so right now the `onChangeText` in the `InputCard` is doing nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, change your `<InputCard>` render like this:

```
   const addInput = () => {
let newFormState = [
            ...formState,
            {
                id: inputList.length,
                substance: "",
                amount: "",
                measure: ""
            },
        ];
setFormState(newFormState);
setInputList(inputList.concat(<InputCard key={inputList.length} id={inputList.length} formState={newFormState} handleChange={handleInputChange}/>));
        
    };
```

You should be passing in the props to the child component. You cannot access `key` property. It is used by react under the hood. Hence use something else, like `id`. Also you should be passing in the new state value into the `<InputCard>`. With your current code the first `inputCard` will not have any data. So instead create the new state value first and then use it.

You also have to set your array state. Since it is an array of objects you need to make a copy and then actually **replace** the object.

```
 const handleInputChange = (index, newStateForIndex) => {
       let newFormState = [...formState];
        setFormState([...newStateForIndex.slice(0, index),
     newStateForIndex,
      ...newStateForIndex.slice(index + 1)]);
    };
```

Now you have to update your call from child component to match the parent components function signature:

```
onChangeText={(event) => {
handleChange(id,{
...formState,
substance : event.target.value //This key will change based on the input field
});
}
}
```

Don't forget to use `id` prop inside your child element, instead of `key`.

**NOTE:**
You are using index as `key` which is not [recommended](https://robinpokorny.medium.com/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318). Try to use a unique id, if you do not have one use a library like `uuid`. Adding to this, your initial code showed that you plan to pass your whole state in your individual inputs. I built the solution on that. But why not pass only the relevant part. Each InputCard should only have its own state's input.

```
<InputCard key={inputList.length} id={inputList.length} individualFormState={formState[inputList.length]} handleChange={handleInputChange}/>
```

and setting state would be even easier.

Comment: So why are we declaring `newFormState` under the `handleInputChange` function?

Also, I'm getting `cannot read undefined` under the `value` prop of `TextInput`, am I reading in `formState` properly? Like so: `const InputCard = (props, { id, formState, handleChange }) => {...` ? And `value={formState[id].substance}` is how I'm reading in value.